# What is this scissors-like tool?

Tags: hand-tools

It sets on a surface on 3 legs, has a pointed tip. What is it? Shaped like scissors but aren't. When you open it a flat piece comes out of the box

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is finger-nail trimmers. The box catches the clippings.

Comment: Looks like a candle wick trimmer

Comment: @ErnstdeRidder you should make [that](http://www.rubylane.com/item/421453-RL00441/Candle-Wick-Trimmer-Legs) an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ernst dR suggested,it's  a wick trimmer. If you run a Google Image search for "antique wick trimmer" you'll get a bunch of similar objects.

(I was thinking maybe cigar cutter, but those are significantly different in design).

Comment: A bit of clarification on the shape: When a candle has a wick that is too long, the flame burns uneven and the candle starts smoking. When you cut off the top, the sooty and possibly smouldering end of the wick ends up safely in the little box instead of on the table cloth. The little legs make sure that candle wax that is on the scissors, does not touch the table cloth (or whatever you put the device on), either.